# Can we use GCM to send push notification wihout starting the app even once as broadcast receiver not working for android 3.0+

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

is there a way so that my application starts automatically right after installation without user interaction because broadcast receiver won't work for version 3.0+.

One solution could be the use of GCM but for that also the app has to be registered on the server before sending push messages.

Can i register the app on the server remotely. For instance via an incoming SMS,that would start the google push service

Answer (score 0):

User will be shown permissions about your app, there is a way an application can start right after installation, and `BroadcastReceiver` work since API Level 1 to the latest API. But since API Level 11 (version 3.0) you need to use this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.mypackage.yourapp.custom.intent.action.ADDON_REQ");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I am actually registering my Broadcast Receiver to receive SMS messages in the manifest file. is there a way i can set the intent to receive broadcasts when my application has not started even once because the OS does not include my app when sending the Broadcast for incoming SMS Message

Comment: what you mean by OS does not include your app when snding the Broadcast for incoming SMS Message

Comment: i mean that my app does not receive the Broadcast sent when the device receives a new SMS. However it does receive the Broadcast if i have started the app once.

Comment: or can you help me with a sample code of starting the app right after installation without user interaction.

Comment: normally a broadcast receiver works after user install it, take a look at this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: No it does not if your app has not been started even once after installation or force closed by the user for version 3.0+

Comment: for version 3.0+ you need to add this as i said in my answer Intent intent = new Intent("com.mypackage.yourapp.custom.intent.action.ADDON_REQ");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34132/discussion-between-test-and-onur-a)